# Cannot install pdftopng

Tags: installation, pip

Trying to install `pdftopng` with `pip` which is version 23.0.1 I get

```
~/06-Projekte/PycharmProjects/sgf2eps % pip install pdftopng
Collecting pdftopng
  Using cached pdftopng-0.1.0.tar.gz (11 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting Click>=7.0
  Using cached click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pdftopng
  Building wheel for pdftopng (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pdftopng (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [35 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.macosx-13-x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build/lib.macosx-13-x86_64-cpython-311/pdftopng
      copying src/pdftopng/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-x86_64-cpython-311/pdftopng
      copying src/pdftopng/__version__.py -> build/lib.macosx-13-x86_64-cpython-311/pdftopng
      running egg_info
      writing src/pdftopng.egg-info/PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to src/pdftopng.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to src/pdftopng.egg-info/requires.txt
      writing top-level names to src/pdftopng.egg-info/top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'src/pdftopng.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      writing manifest file 'src/pdftopng.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
      copying src/pdftopng/pdftopng.cpp -> build/lib.macosx-13-x86_64-cpython-311/pdftopng
      running build_ext
      creating var
      creating var/folders
      creating var/folders/rf
      creating var/folders/rf/5wykxh413gg6djy1vmg0ypww0000gn
      creating var/folders/rf/5wykxh413gg6djy1vmg0ypww0000gn/T
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -c /var/folders/rf/5wykxh413gg6djy1vmg0ypww0000gn/T/tmpl6tvr13s.cpp -o var/folders/rf/5wykxh413gg6djy1vmg0ypww0000gn/T/tmpl6tvr13s.o -std=c++14
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -c /var/folders/rf/5wykxh413gg6djy1vmg0ypww0000gn/T/tmpav4l0ebv.cpp -o var/folders/rf/5wykxh413gg6djy1vmg0ypww0000gn/T/tmpav4l0ebv.o -fvisibility=hidden
      building 'pdftopng.pdftopng' extension
      creating build/temp.macosx-13-x86_64-cpython-311
      creating build/temp.macosx-13-x86_64-cpython-311/src
      creating build/temp.macosx-13-x86_64-cpython-311/src/pdftopng
      clang -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -DVERSION_INFO=\"0.1.0\" -Ilib/poppler -Ilib/poppler/fofi -Ilib/poppler/goo -Ilib/poppler/poppler -Ilib/poppler/build -Ilib/poppler/build/poppler -Ilib/poppler/utils -Ilib/poppler/build/utils -I/private/var/folders/rf/5wykxh413gg6djy1vmg0ypww0000gn/T/pip-build-env-xio3q4pz/overlay/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pybind11/include -I/usr/local/opt/python@3.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/include/python3.11 -c src/pdftopng/pdftopng.cpp -o build/temp.macosx-13-x86_64-cpython-311/src/pdftopng/pdftopng.o -O3 -Wall -shared -fPIC -stdlib=libc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 -std=c++14 -fvisibility=hidden
      clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-shared' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
      src/pdftopng/pdftopng.cpp:44:10: fatal error: 'config.h' file not found
      #include "config.h"
               ^~~~~~~~~~
      1 error generated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pdftopng
Failed to build pdftopng
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pdftopng, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

The strange thing is, that I already had `pdftopng` installed and it has been working. I don't know what happens.